# Variable effect in Weibull and Cox models

Tags: survival, cox-model, weibull-distribution

Is it possible to compare effect of variable on the survival time in the Cox model and in the Weibull regression model?

Comment: If the Weibull model is proportional hazards (which would be the usual case), then the estimate of that proportionality should be comparable, at least if the Weibull model is not fair from reasonable.